# How to match umlauts with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

In German text, umlauts (ä, ü, ö) and eszett (ß) are regular letters, but they don't seem to be covered by the `\w` special character:

```
In [1]: re.match('(\w+)', 'Straße').groups()
Out[1]: ('Stra',)
```

Passing the `re.UNICODE` flag to `re.match` doesn't change anything.

Is there any better way to match a full word other than with `[a-zA-ZäüöÄÜÖß]+`?

Comment: Is it Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 2

Comment: I cannot repro: see [`re.match(ur'(\w+)', u'Straße', flags=re.U).group(1).encode("utf8")`](https://ideone.com/R1xTej), it prints `Straße`. Maybe you just missed `u""` prefixes? `\w` covers all Unicode letters in fact when you pass the `re.U` flag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should post that as answer. that is the answer. I get the same result as @elpres when I use his code. it definitely needs the `u` prefix.

Comment: I prefer to not answer such frequent duplicates.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, the `u''` prefix does indeed solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using python 2, you need to use unicode strings:

```
print re.match(ur'(\w+)',u'Straße',re.UNICODE).groups()[0]
Straße
```

Comment: You don't need the `u` in `u'(\w+)'` but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: You're right, it works when there are both a `u''` string and the `re.UNICODE` flag. Thanks!

Comment: A hint: use raw string literals when defining a regex pattern.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I was rushing and it didn't happen to matter in this instance.